# Scanner#nextDouble fails to parse 5.2 (InputMismatchException)

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

### Problem

I was messing around with Java today, and bumped into something that I can't fix by myself. I'm trying to get a double value from scanner but always get this error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Source code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final char ADD = '+';
        final char SUBTRACT = '-';
        final char MULTIPLY = '*';
        final char DIVIDE = '/';

        double num1;
        double num2;

        char operator;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        num1 = sc.nextDouble();
        num2 = sc.nextDouble();
        operator = sc.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.print(num1 + " " + operator + " " + num2 + " = ");

        switch (operator) {
        case ADD:
            System.out.print(num1 + num2);
            break;
        case SUBTRACT:
            System.out.print(num1 - num2);
            break;
        case MULTIPLY:
            System.out.print(num1 * num2);
            break;
        case DIVIDE:
            System.out.print(num1 / num2);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My input:

```java
5.2
```

And then the exception is thrown.

I also have a small video illustrating the problem: https://streamable.com/wes4g1

---

### Minimal example

I was even able to reproduce the issue with a very minimal setup like:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double value = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

with the input `5.2` or any other decimal.

Inputing an actual integer value, for example just `5` works however.

Comment: Is that your entire input? Your code attempts to read to read two doubles from stdin

Comment: @Mureinik yes that's the entire input, i type 5.2 and the exception is thrown.

Comment: This can't be the input causing the error as this will perfectly work given the `num1 = sc.nextDouble();` statement. Are you performing any additional keystroke?

Comment: May it be a problem with my eclipse ide or kind of? I don't type anything else than this. Also the thing is that if i type a int number, for example 5, then everything works fine

Comment: Can't reproduce - I ran this locally and after the 5.2 input it just hangs and waits for the next input, as expected. Can you share some details on how you tun this?

Comment: Voting to close, not reproducible

Comment: https://streamable.com/wes4g1 Here is a video of what's happening. What kind of details should i share?

Comment: Whats the system language set on your machine? For countries like germany you have to input a comma, like `5,2` instead. Try to enter it in the way expected by your current machines country/language settings (locale). If thats the issue and you dont want that, you can easily change the locale that Java uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Scanner and Locale

It is not directly obvious from the Javadoc of [`Scanner#nextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) but it is **Locale-sensitive**.

There are various things that influence the way how `Scanner` expects numbers and text to look like that depend on your current set `Locale`.

By default, `Scanner` uses your current systems locale (country and language settings). So you have to enter the numbers in the way they are usually written in your current region.

### Decimal separator . vs ,

In your particular case, it is the **decimal separator** which you entered with `.` (dot) but `Scanner` expected a `,` (comma) instead. This is for example the case with a Moldovan locale, since in Moldovan comma is used instead.

Hence, when you entered `5.2` it did not *see* any `double`, as specified by your current `Locale`. But when you enter `5,2`, it works.

You can read more about this in the Javadoc of `Scanner`, section **Localized numbers**. Also see this illustration from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma):

[image: Countries using decimal comma]

### Change locale

That said, you can use `Scanner#useLocale` to change the locale `Scanner` uses. For example:

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

and then you can also work with `5.2` as input.

Answer (score 1):

All i had to do was using comma instead of a dot, "5,2" instead of "5.2".
Big thanks to @Zabuzard. He pointed out the solution.